Terraform Error while creating Resource Group in Azure
I am getting the below error while trying to create an RG
Error: Unsupported attribute
on helpers.tf line 36, in module "resource_group":
  for_each = local.region.enable_rg == true ? toset(module.naming.rg_configurations.subscription_type) : toset([])
module.naming is object with no attributes
This object does not have an attribute named "rg_configurations".

region_manifest.tf
locals {
  regions_defaults = {
    instance_number = "001"
  }
}

locals {
  regions_manifest = {
    eus = {
      azure_region        = "eastus"
      enable_rg           = true 
      environments = {
        dv = {
          environment     = "${var.app_environment}"
        }
        tst = {
          environment     = "${var.app_environment}"
         }
        prod = {
          environment     = "${var.app_environment}"
         }
      }
    }
    wus = {
      azure_region        = "westus"
      enable_rg           = true

      environments = {
        dv = {
          environment     = "${var.app_environment}"
        }
        tst = {
          environment     = "${var.app_environment}"
         }
        prod = {
          environment     = "${var.app_environment}"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}

helpers.tf
locals {
  region = { for x in flatten([
    for region_key, region in local.regions_manifest : [
      for environment_key, environment in region.environments : merge(local.regions_defaults, region, environment, {
        app_region                           = region_key
        app_environment                      = environment_key
        environments                         = null
        regions                              = null
      })
    ]
  ]) : "${x.app_region}_${x.app_environment}" => x }["${var.app_region}_${var.app_environment}"]
}

## Naming ## 

module "naming" {
  source            = "./modules/names"
  rg_configurations = [
    {
      #environment       = "${var.app_environment}"
      subscription_type = "lux",
      rg_type           = "shrd"
      instance_number   = "001"
    },
    {
      #environment       = "${var.app_environment}"
      subscription_type = "lux",
      rg_type           = "shrd"
      instance_number   = "002"
    }
  ]
}

module "resource_group" {
  for_each = local.region.enable_rg == true ? toset(module.naming.rg_configurations) : toset([])
  source   = "./modules/resource_group"
  rg_name  = "${each.value}-${local.prefix}"
  location = local.region.azure_region
  tags     = local.custom_tags
}

variables.tf
variable "client_id" {}

variable "client_secret" {}

variable "tenant_id" {}

variable "subscription_id" {}


variable "application_name" {
  description = "Application or Service Name"
}

variable "subscription_type" {
  description = "Subscription Type: app (Application), conn (connectivity), dt (devtest), id (identity), mgmt (management), prod (production)"
}

variable "app_environment" {
  description = "Environment: dev, qa,test, prod,hub,spoke,stage"
  default = "dv"
  validation {
    condition = contains(["dv","tst","qa","uat","prod","dr"],var.app_environment)
    error_message = "Valid values for environment are dv,tst,qa,uat,prod,dr"
  }
}

variable "app_region" {
  description = "Azure Location (see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies/#overview)"
}

variable "enable_rg" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Controls the deployment of the Rgs and its supporting infrastructure"
  default     = false
}

local values
locals {
  custom_tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
    Department  = "Finance"
    Owner       = "Pallab"
  }
}

locals {
  prefix          = "${var.app_environment}-${var.app_region}"
  workload_type   = "app"
  compute_snet    = "ComputeSubnet"
  pvtlink_snet    = "PrivatelinkSubnet"
  resource_group_log_alert = ["log"]
  subresource_names_sa     = ["blob"]
  subresource_names_kv     = ["Vault"]
}

modules/names folder
## names ##

locals {
  az = {
    # virtual_networks = [for vnet in var.vnet_configurations : { name = format("vnet-%s-%s-%s-%s", vnet.subscription_type, vnet.environment, vnet.region, vnet.instance_number) } ]
    # subnet = [for snet in var.snet_configurations : { name = format("snet-%s-%s-%s", snet.subscription_type, snet.subnet_type, snet.instance_number) } ]
    rg = [for rg in var.rg_configurations : { name = format("rg-%s-%s-%s", rg.subscription_type, rg.rg_type, rg.instance_number) } ]
    # kv = [for kv in var.kv_configurations : { name = format("kv-%s-%s-%s-%s", kv.subscription_type, kv.kv_type,kv.region,kv.instance_number) } ] 
    # lga = [for lga in var.lga_configurations : { name = format("lg-%s-%s-%s-%s", lga.subscription_type, lga.lga_type,lga.region,lga.instance_number) } ]
    # vm = [for vm in var.vm_configurations : { name = format("vm-%s-%s", vm.vm_name,vm.instance_number) } ]
  }
}


## var.tf ##

variable "instance_number" {
  description = "Resource Number"
  type        = string
  default     = "001"
}


variable "rg_configurations" {
  description = "List of maps containing VM configurations"
  type = list(object({
    #environment        : string
    subscription_type  : string
    rg_type            : string
    instance_number    : string
  }))
}

modules/resource_group folder
## rg.tf ##

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = var.rg_name
  location = var.location
  tags     = var.tags
}

## var.tf ## 

variable "location" {
}

variable "rg_name" {}

variable "tags" {}


What does regions_manifest and region_defaults contains? @Pallab

I have made below modifications to your .tf codes accordingly and it worked as expected without any conflicts.
The issue is that the module.naming object is not correctly addressing or returning the rg_configurations attribute. Make sure that it is declared and referred correctly in the terraform configuration. And also include an output block to retrieve the rg_configurations values.
helpers.tf:
provider "azurerm"{
  features{}
  subscription_id = "xxxx"
}
locals {
  region = { for x in flatten([
    for region_key, region in local.regions_manifest : [
      for environment_key, environment in region.environments : merge(local.regions_defaults, region, environment, {
        app_region                           = region_key
        app_environment                      = environment_key
        environments                         = null
        regions                              = null
        enable_rg                            = var.enable_rg
      })
    ]
  ]) : "${x.app_region}_${x.app_environment}" => x }["${var.app_region}_${var.app_environment}"]
}

## Naming ## 
module "naming" {
  source            = "./naming"
  rg_configurations = [
    {
      #environment       = "${var.app_environment}"
      subscription_type = "lux",
      rg_type           = "shrd"
      instance_number   = "001"
    },
    {
      #environment       = "${var.app_environment}"
      subscription_type = "lux",
      rg_type           = "shrd"
      instance_number   = "002"
    }
  ]
}


module "resource_group" {
  for_each = local.region.enable_rg == true ? toset(module.naming.rg_configurations) : toset([])
  source   = "./resource_group"
  rg_name  = "${each.value}-${local.prefix}"
  location = local.region.azure_region
  tags     = local.custom_tags
}

locals.tf:
locals {
  custom_tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
    Department  = "Finance"
    Owner       = "Pallab"
  }
}

locals {
  prefix          = "${var.app_environment}-${var.app_region}"
  workload_type   = "app"
  compute_snet    = "ComputeSubnet"
  pvtlink_snet    = "PrivatelinkSubnet"
  resource_group_log_alert = ["log"]
  subresource_names_sa     = ["blob"]
  subresource_names_kv     = ["Vault"]
}
locals {
  regions_defaults = {
    env_short_name = "uat"
    instance_number = "001"
  }
}

locals {
  regions_manifest = {
    euz = {
      azure_region        = "eastus"
      environments = {
        dv = {
            env_short_name = "dev"
            instance_number = "001"
        }
        tst = {
          env_short_name = "tst"
          instance_number = "002"
         }

      }

    }
    wuz = {
      azure_region        = "westus"
      environments = {
        dv = {
            env_short_name = "dev"
            instance_number = "001"
        }
        tst = {
          env_short_name = "tst"
          instance_number = "002"
         }

      }

    }

  }
}

variables.tf:
variable "client_id" {}

variable "client_secret" {}

variable "tenant_id" {}

variable "subscription_id" {}


variable "application_name" {
  description = "Application or Service Name"
}

variable "subscription_type" {
  description = "Subscription Type: app (Application), conn (connectivity), dt (devtest), id (identity), mgmt (management), prod (production)"
}

variable "app_environment" {
  description = "Environment: dev, qa,test, prod,hub,spoke,stage"
  default = "dv"
  validation {
    condition = contains(["dv","tst","qa","uat","prod","dr"],var.app_environment)
    error_message = "Valid values for environment are dv,tst,qa,uat,prod,dr"
  }
}

variable "app_region" {
  description = "Azure Location (see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies/#overview)"
}

variable "enable_rg" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Controls the deployment of the Rgs and its supporting infrastructure"
  default     = false
}

modules/naming/main.tf:
output  "rg_configurations"  {
value = var.rg_configurations
}

variables.tf:
variable "instance_number" {
  description = "Resource Number"
  type        = string
  default     = "001"
}
variable "rg_configurations" {
  description = "List of maps containing VM configurations"
  type = list(object({
    #environment        : string
    subscription_type  : string
    rg_type            : string
    instance_number    : string
  }))
}

modules/resource_group/resource_group.tf
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = var.rg_name
  location = var.location
  tags     = var.tags
}

## var.tf ## 

variable "location" {
}

variable "rg_name" {}

variable "tags" {}

Output:


I have added now region_manifest. If you put  source as "./naming" in helpers.tf i get the below error :  Error: Unreadable module directory│
│ Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat naming: no such file or directory╷
│ Error: Unreadable module directory│
│ The directory  could not be read for module "naming" at helpers.tf:17.╷
│ Error: Unreadable module directory│
│ Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat resource_group: no such file or
│ directory╵╷
│ Error: Unreadable module directory│
│ The directory  could not be read for module "resource_group" at
│ helpers.tf:36.

My modules folder is one level up and it has two subfolders : names and resource_group where the child modules are. So it should be ./modules/names and ./modules/resource_group

Ok in that case your root module is modules. Right? @Pallab

You need to give source as ./modules/names. @Pallab

If i give source = "./modules/names" , i get the below error which i pasted in the beginning --> Error: Unsupported attribute
on helpers.tf line 37, in module "resource_group":
for_each = local.region.enable_rg == true ? toset(module.naming.rg_configurations) : toset([])
module.naming is object with no attributes
This object does not have an attribute named "rg_configurations".

You said when you are adding ./naming then the error is occurring right? @Pallab

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Is the issue resolved now. @Pallab

I pasted the error in our chat if you see after code modification. The RG keeps on getting deleted and new one is created. Please check our chat

Ok will check it. @Pallab
